# "Could not execute application" for streaming application deployed from Kinesis Analytics Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-zeppelin, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I have a Kinesis Analytics Studio notebook that is working well, and I'm trying to deploy the solution as an application by following the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/example-notebook-deploy.html#example-notebook-deploy-console) (the steps for console), but I'm running into a few problems. The notebook contains a python udf that it needs to function properly, but first, even when I comment everything regarding the udf out, I get the following message logged 4 times per start of run for the application:

```
locationInformation com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.GlueMetastoreClientDelegate.getFunction(GlueMetastoreClientDelegate.java:1915)
logger  com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.GlueMetastoreClientDelegate
message software.amazon.kinesisanalytics.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.EntityNotFoundException: Cannot find function. (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityNotFoundException; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx; Proxy: null)
```

Despite these messages, CloudWatch shows me the application still runs. Now if I add in the udf (registered using `st_env.register_function()`), the application doesn't run, and I get an additional 4 error messages:

1

```
Exception occurred in REST handler: Could not execute application.
locationInformation org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.AbstractHandler.handleException(AbstractHandler.java:251)
logger  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler
message Exception occurred in REST handler: Could not execute application.
```

2

```
Error occurred when trying to start the job
locationInformation org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$4(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:244)
logger  org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler
message Error occurred when trying to start the job
```

```
throwableInformation
java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:124) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$3(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:238) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[?:?]
... 6 more
Wrapped by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:134) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$3(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:238) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) ~[?:?]
... 6 more
Wrapped by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

3

```
Run python process failed
locationInformation org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:127)
logger org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver
message Run python process failed
```

```
throwableInformation
java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:124) ~[PythonApplicationDependencies.jar:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$3(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:238) ~[flink-dist_2.12-1.13.2.jar:1.13.2]
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

4

```
errorCode CodeError.InvalidApplicationCode
```

```
message

org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.handler.RestHandlerException: Could not execute application.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$4(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:247)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1705)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1702)
... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramAbortException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:134)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.tryExecuteJobs(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.DetachedApplicationRunner.run(DetachedApplicationRunner.java:70)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunOverrideHandler.lambda$handleRequest$3(JarRunOverrideHandler.java:238)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Python process exits with code: 1
at org.apache.flink.client.python.PythonDriver.main(PythonDriver.java:124)
... 17 more
```

Also of note, the file the studio builds and exports to S3 is a jar file when the udf is commented out, and a zip file when it isn't. Would appreciate any help with understanding the problem, thanks!

Comment: i get the same error after creating a Streaming Application via AWS Console. Any updates here?